# Looping though data multiple times from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, while-loop

I'm looking to loop through data multiple times if it's stored in the array multiple times.

I'm storing video ID's in a database as an array, I'm then calling this data using the following code;

```
$lessonSingleResultsql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM `video` 
 WHERE `id` IN ('".$lessonsResultDataDecode."') 
 ORDER 
    BY field(id,'".$lessonsResultDataDecode."');";

$lessonSingleResult = $db->prepare($lessonSingleResultsql);
if ($lessonSingleResult->execute()) {
while ($row = $lessonSingleResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo $row['title'];
}
}
```

Value of $lessonResultDataDecode

```
 1','5','7','11','12','1','1','4','4','4','4','4','4','2','2','1','4','1','1','1','1','1','9','6','1
```

Value of $lessonsResultData

```
 Array
 (
     [videos] => [1,5,7,11,12,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,1,4,1,1,1,1,1,9,6,1]
 )
```

It will then echo the title for each video once but if the value is store multiple times I'd like to echo again.

e.g Title for 1, Title for 5,Title for 7,Title for 11,Title for 12,Title for 1,Title for 1, etc...

Comment: Incidentally, your not preparing your query properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sure if this will help you because the result that you ask for is a little confused, but if you want loop through array that you receive as result from you query you can do something like:

```php
    #as i don't know your table schema i'll assume that title have an array called videos
    while ($row = $lessonSingleResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $allTitles[] = $row['title']['videos'];
    }
    #iterate all the titles received from query
    foreach($allTitles as $titles){
        #iterates through each key inside of each title
        foreach($titles as $title){
            echo "Title for {$title}".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php